# How to escape DecimalFormat pattern symbol in java

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to format the number with DecimalFormat pattern symbol. Any idea to do??

Ex: ### 123 dollars and 00 cents ###

where 123 is need to formatted using DecimalFormat.format method

In C#, it is possible with escape("\") character. Is there any similar way in java?

```
double value = 123;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("\\#\\#\\# ##0 dollars and \\0\\0 cents \\#\\#\\#"));
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? What pattern do you want to use to format the number? Your question is too vague.

Comment: Write some code for the reference, Not able to understand what you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the characters to the beginning and end of the string.

```
System.out.println("### " & formattedString & " ###")
```

It's more readable that way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
String pattern = "###,###,### Dolars ";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
System.out.println("###" + decimalFormat.format(123456789) + "00 cents ###");
```

but you can't write XX cents dinamically.

This can be a workaround but it's still ugly:

```
String pattern = "###,###,###.###";
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('$');
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(123456789.123) + " cents");
```

prints

```
123.456.789$123 cents.
```